# Sending object with $http in AngularJs

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Angular seems so elegant but when I try and send this $http request I get a 500 error.

```
    $scope.UpdateOrganization = function (organization) {
        var jsonOrg = JSON.stringify(organization);

        var url = 'Organization/UpdateOrganization/' + organization.ActorId;

        $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: url,
            data: jsonOrg,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).success(function (data, status) {
        }).error(function (data, status) {
        });
    }
```

On the receiving end, I am using an MVC controller. The method is like this:

```
    // PUT: api/Organization/guid
    [HttpPut]
    public string UpdateOrganization(Guid id, Organization organization)
    {

    }
```

Basically, I want the C# controller to receive the Angular PUT. However, the failure has something to do with the data: jsonOrg in the $http call.

Just to clarify, I have also tried $http.put() with no success. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: You should really include the error. As far as I can tell from the quick glance, action parameters do not match the JSON data you're passing; it should probably be `data : { id : /* get the guid from somewhere */, organization: jsonOrg }`

Comment: I think @PatrykĆwiek is correct. From the code it looks like you are only passing the organization object to the endpoint, and are not providing the Guid.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the method signature in your controller to this:

```
// PUT: api/Organization/guid
[HttpPut]
public string UpdateOrganization(Guid id, [FromBody]Organization organization)
{

}
```